# alter table add foreign key fails

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and they all have innodb engine:

```
video(url, title, desc, country,...) url -> primary key
videoCat(_url, category) {_url,category} -> primary key
favorite(fav_url, thumb_path) fav_url -> primary key
```

then I do:

```
alter table favorite
add foreign key(fav_url) references video(url)
on delete cascade
```

and everything goes smooth, but when I try:

```
alter table videoCat
add foreign key(_url) references video(url)
on delete cascade
```

I get:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bascelik_lookaroundyou`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-efa_1a6e91a'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-efa_1a6e91a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_url`) REFERENCES `video` (`url`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

why???

p.s. I am using phpmyadmin ver. 3.3.9.2

Comment: See there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770035/handling-database-integrity (duplicate)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The table videoCat has one or more rows that violates the foreign key constraint. This is usually that you have a row with a value for _url that does not exist in the table video.

You can check for this with the following query:

```
SELECT videoCat._url
FROM videoCat LEFT JOIN video ON videoCat._url = video.url
WHERE video.url IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

Per request, here's a query to delete those pesky rows:

```
DELETE FROM videoCat
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM video
    WHERE url = videoCat._url
)
```

Comment: yes, u r right. that is it!! many thanks. is there a select query to get those out of videoCat? ;)

Comment: and please, how would you delete them all with one query?