# I get Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table where I keep 
id|user_id|subject_id

I have another two table users and subjects.
user_id is a foriegn key and refer the id in users table id column.
I use php admin and I could create the relation.

Same way, I tried to create relation for the subject_id foriegn key.
But I get the following error.

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`version2`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-25b4_1e1'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-25b4_1e1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `wp_cons_table` (`subject_id`))
```

all tables are ino db and columns have int(5) data type. 
I don't know why I get the error.
Can someone figure the reson to this error.

Comment: "Same way, I tried to create relation" could you show _how you tried_? Please post your query. And maybe your table structure (`EXPLAIN TABLE ...` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE...`)

Comment: Most likely the first table contains one or more rows with a `subject_id` value that is not present among the values of `subjects(id)`

Comment: I created from phpadmin but when imported the previous query, I got this.` ALTER TABLE `wp_cons_users`  ADD CONSTRAINT `wp_cons_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `wp_cons_table` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966626/mysql-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Answer (score 1):

The specific link it's failing on is described at the end of your error:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `wp_cons_table` (`subject_id`)
```

It would be useful to have clearer information about the tables but essentially there are values already in your child table that do not exist in the parent table.

If there is any data that would violate the constraint then you won't be allowed to create it. Delete the mismatched child data or create the parents and you should be fine.

See also: [alter table add foreign key fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903625/alter-table-add-foreign-key-fails)